# CTS and the mouse

Tags: mouse, rsi

This isn't the same question as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/2198/mouse-recommendation), but what is the best mouse for RSI?

What sorts of alterative pointers have people used that weren't awkward, clumsy, or overly expensive?

Comment: This SE proposal might interest you: [Hardware Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations?referrer=pkyzvJvq0mtg1JcHSmnJDQ2).

Comment: Sounds exciting. Good hardware is expensive but I find usually worth it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about RSI, a trackball is definitely the way to go. They're a little difficult to get used to, but you'll notice a difference really quickly.

Comment: I <3 my trackball.

Answer (score 2):

I switch my mouse between my left and right hand daily. It was a bit awkward using my off hand at first but after a few hours I was almost at my usual speed.

Comment: You can also switch between different mouse sizes/forms.

Answer (score 1):

A great mouse alternative I use (I'm a computer scientist): http://www.naturalpoint.com/smartnav/

[image]

Works great even with "big" setup such as mine:

[image]

How SmartNAV works: http://www.naturalpoint.com/smartnav/products/about.html

> SmartNav uses an infrared (IR) camera to track your head movements.
> Learn more about the technology. You reflect IR light back to the
> SmartNav, which sends instructions to your computer to move your mouse
> cursor.
>
> HOW DOES THE TECHNOLOGY WORK? Infrared light is emitted from the LEDs
> and is reflected back to the imager by a corner cube reflector (3M
> safety material). This reflected light is imaged by a CMOS sensor and
> the video signal is passed to the preprocessing electronics. The video
> signal is thresholded against a reference level and all passing data
> is sent to the USB microcontroller to send to the PC for object
> tracking. In order to increase the signal to noise ratio an IR filter
> that passes only 800nm and above is placed between the imager lens and
> the outside world. The SmartNav can image any IR source; typically
> this is reflective material or an active IR source such as an LED. A
> user may track many different objects by placing reflective dots or
> LEDs on the object. The SmartNav has a 45 degree field of view and
> anything being tracked must stay in that field of view.
>
> HOW IS MY HEAD MOVEMENT TRACKED? SmartNav tracks reflections
> from a tiny dot, which you can place anywhere.
>
> Place our paper thin tiny reflective dot on the part of your body
> you'd like to control the cursor with. Preferred options include: Head
> Hand Hat Glasses Mic Boom You can also make your own reflective marker
> with NaturalPoint's high-quality tracking material available on our
> Accessories page.

[image]

> WHERE DO I PUT THE SMARTNAV? SmartNav mounts on top
> of your monitor, laptop or communication device facing you. SmartNav
> can also be threaded onto a mini tripod and sit next to your computer.
> The device can be placed anywhere as long as it can see the reflective
> accessory you've chosen to wear.
>
> HOW MUCH DO I MOVE? Less than an inch
> of head movement is more than enough to move the cursor across your
> entire screen. This is also adjustable in the software SPEED settings.
> SmartNav has a 45 degree Field of View (FOV), and usually sits about 2
> feet away from your head. Thus you have almost two feet of free "head
> space" in which to move that simple inch.
>
> HOW DO I CLICK? SmartNav
> offers multiple clicking options. Hotkeys: Re-map keys from your
> keyboard and assign them to emulate the Left, Right and Middle mouse
> buttons. Dwell-Clicking Software: Click by hovering the cursor in one
> spot for a small (and adjustable) amount of time. A full
> dwell-clicking system and on-screen keyboard are included in the AT
> software package, allowing for total hands free operation. Ability
> Switches: Industry standard input switch support allows you to plug
> two click switches into SmartNav for more clicking options. Choose
> from our full selection of hand and foot switches on our Accessories
> page.

I wrote an article about it exploring other solutions. http://francky.me/doc/mouse2012.pdf

http://francky.me/publications.php#mouse2012 :

> Abstract—In a few months the computer mouse will be
> half-a-century-old. It is known to have many drawbacks, the main ones
> being: loss of productivity due to constant switching between keyboard
> and mouse, health issues such as RSI, medical impossibility to use the
> mouse e.g. broken or amputated arm and unnatural human-computer
> interface like the keyboard. However almost everybody still uses a
> computer mouse nowadays.
>
> In this short article, we explore computer mouse alternatives. Our
> research shows that moving the mouse cursor can be done efficiently
> with the SmartNav device and mouse clicks can be emulated in many
> complementary ways. We believe that computer users can increase their
> productivity and their health by using those alternatives.
>
> This article is voluntary short and not overly technical, our main
> motivation being to make the readers aware of these solutions and
> their efficiencies. Details can be found in the appendices and by
> following the URLs and references. The primarily intended readers are
> computer scientists, people with RSI, physicians and interface
> pioneers. Feedback is highly welcome: this is work in progress.

Comment: How does it work? Motion? Does it need anything fancy to track?

Comment: SmartNav uses an infrared (IR) camera to track head movements. More details in edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I myself haven't come even close to a "alterative pointers have people used that weren't awkward, clumsy, or overly expensive?"

(By the way I cannot see how a pointer could be awkward and clumsy and ergonomics at the same time, it's some sort of an oxymoron.)

But I can recommend you going through this checklist: http://capsoff.org/checklist when considering any solution touted as "ergonomic".