# Win 7 - web browsing with speech recognition

Tags: windows-7, speech-recognition, voice-command

How can I quickly access links on webpages using speech recognition?

Using mousegrids is clumsy at best. I know this is similiar to asking "how can I browse the web without a mouse," but looking at other questions in SO and elsewhere has yielded not much.

Setup: Windows 7, built-in speech recognition, IE 10.

Comment: What speech recognition software are you using?

Comment: Just the normal Win7 speech recognition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Speech Recognition (only works with Internet Explorer):

- If you want to click a link, just say the link's name: like "Badges" (on this site)
- Alternative: say "Show numbers" and the software will create a number for each item on the screen, including HTML links in Internet Explorer. Then say the number and "OK", that is: "14 OK"

Further information about voice commands for Windows Speech Recognition can be found here: 
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/common-commands-in-speech-recognition

Dragon NaturallySpeaking (only Internet Explorer and Firefox):

- Say "Click name of the link", e.g. "Click Badges"

In the help to Dragon, you can actually find quite a lot of relevant articles and other commands.

For Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer there is support for Gmail and Outlook.com if you want to dictate as you would in Word. Other than that, it doesn't work.

You may want to look for an extension that assigns numbers to links for browsers other than Internet Explorer. Then you could just say the number to click the link.

Do you to the constantly changing offer of extensions that can do this, please use this search engine link to search for current solutions:

- [Chrome](https://www.google.ch/search?q=mouseless%20browsing%20chrome)
- [Firefox](https://www.google.ch/search?q=mouseless%20browsing%20firefox)

Comment: Also, I'm curious if this works for Chrome as well?

Comment: @AaronThomas Not to the best of my knowledge. I've added some info regarding other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a Dragon NaturallySpeaking extension called [Utter Command](http://www.redstartsystems.com/uttercommand.html) that add some interesting comment to browse the web by voice as you can see in this video: 
[Utter Command -- Browsing the Web with Firefox](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiN76nGZihc) . Utter Command rely on the Firefox extension [Mouseless Browsing](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/mouseless-browsing/), which is pretty good except that it does not working well for some websites, typically those with some advanced UI loaded with JS.

Personally I use a [hands-free mouse](https://superuser.com/a/435277/116475) for browsing and Dragon only for typing, I find this setup more efficient.